# Creating a DD-MM-YYYY combo textbox helper for mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Howdy,
I am wanting to create a helper for an mvc project I am working on. If you think of a form that requires a persons DOB. I am wanting to 3 textboxes, one for each of the fields.

How is my best way to achieve this, do I create an editor template or do I need to create a full helper for this?

Any tips would be great!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the person's DOB is a datetime, This is how I would approach this:

If I want every DateTime editor (through the whole application) to be created as 3 textboxes I'd use an Editor Template. However, I'd bet this is probably not true, as it's probably true that you'll need different editors for datetimes (say a jquery datepicker or something), so I'd go with a Html Helper.

BTW I would reconsider using 3 textboxes and would use something like a [jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Comment: Thanks Linkgoron, I think the 3 textbox approach is better to collect a persons dob as the datepicker is a bit of a pain trying to go back 20 + years.